# Linker error about symbol from a discarded segment being referenced (ONLY IN DEBUG MODE

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, g++, linker-errors

I'm getting the most bizarre linker error. Here is the error using two different linkers. I believe this is from the default G++ linker.

```
../../bin/LinuxARM/Debug/libGJGO.a(scene_management_layer.o)(.data+0x208): error: relocation refers to local symbol "_ZZN4entt8internal9type_nameIN4GJGO20Transform2DComponentEEEDavE19__PRETTY_FUNCTION__" [998], which is defined in a discarded section
  section group signature: "_ZZN4entt9type_nameIN4GJGO20Transform2DComponentEvE5valueEvE5value"
  prevailing definition is from obj/LinuxARM/Debug/src/main.o
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And this one is from the gold linker, IIRC.

```
`_ZZN4entt8internal9type_nameIN4GJGO20Transform2DComponentEEEDavE19__PRETTY_FUNCTION__' referenced in section `.data' of ../../bin/LinuxARM/Debug/libGJGO.a(scene_management_layer.o): defined in discarded section `.rodata._ZZN4entt8internal9type_nameIN4GJGO20Transform2DComponentEEEDavE19__PRETTY_FUNCTION__[_ZZN4entt9type_nameIN4GJGO20Transform2DComponentEvE5valueEvE5value]' of ../../bin/LinuxARM/Debug/libGJGO.a(scene_management_layer.o)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It appears to be caused by the "auto view" line of this code

```cpp
void SceneManagementLayer::draw()
{
    GJGO_PROFILE_FUNCTION();

    if (g_appInstancePtr->currentScene->primaryCamera)
    {
        auto view = g_appInstancePtr->currentScene->m_registry.view<Transform2DComponent, SpriteComponent>();
        for (const entt::entity l_entity : view)
        {
            auto[transform, sprite] = view.get<Transform2DComponent, SpriteComponent>(l_entity);

            Renderer::begin2D(Renderer::defaultSpriteShader, *g_appInstancePtr->currentScene->primaryCamera, GJGO::Window::getWidth(), GJGO::Window::getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

As the title states, this issue *only* appears in Debug mode, not in my other modes (Release and Dist). Additionally, I have a friend who suspects the function is being discarded by the compiler because it has some form of UB in it, but I can't find anything out of the ordinary. Any help is greatly appropriated, I've been pulling my hair out over this for hours.

P.S. Sorry if I did something wrong, I'm new hear. Also, let me know if I should update with any more information, I'm just trying not to clutter the post with a billion pointless details.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620868/c17-lto-static-libstdc-issue-warning-relocation-refers-to-discarded-sec) help?

Comment: @john That seems to pertain to code that gives warnings yet still links. Mine gives an error and does not link.

Comment: I'd guess that this `GJGO_PROFILE_FUNCTION` is a macro that uses `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`? Maybe its definition is different in debug vs release mode? Can you post its definition?